# How to play video in all browser/device using JW Player?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, video, jwplayer

I using JW Player in my proyect that contain many videos in formats: MP4, FLV, OGV, WMV

I read the documentation of the diferent formats that each browser support. So, now i using MP4 (Chrome, Safari), FLV(IE,7,8,9) and WEBM(Mozilla).

```
jwplayer('container').setup({
                height: 309,
                width: 549,
                levels: [
                    { file: "video.mp4" },
                    { file: "video.webm" },
                    { file: "video.flv" }
                ], 
                'modes': [
                    {type: 'html5'},
                    {type: 'flash', src: "jwplayer.flash.swf"},
                    {type: 'download'}
                ]
});
```

My question is, if this code doing: Check the browser if support HTML5 or FLASH -> Depend of browser reproduce MP4(Chrome - Safari) or FLV(IE) or WEBM(Mozilla) automatically.

Because, in mozilla especially, for first time i have the message: "ERROR LOADING MEDIA: File could not be played"
.Then when i click 2 or 1 time, play the video.

Maybe this occurs for the order of files?

---

### UPDATE

I changed my mime.conf settings and .htaccess, adding the following lines:

NOTE: I use the .htaccess of Drupal in my Codeigniter Project

.htaccess:

```
#
# Apache/PHP/Drupal settings:
#

#For disable gzip
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(og[gv]|mp4|m4v|webm)$ no-gzip dont-vary

#For add mime types
AddType video/ogg  .ogv
AddType video/mp4  .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
[...]
```

mime.conf

```
#
# If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
# probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
#
AddType application/x-compress .Z
#AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
AddType application/x-bzip2 .bz2
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
```

I disable gzip compress but the problem persist.. Only my app into iframe of facebook fail the video webm. MP4 Works fine.

---

### UPDATE 2

The problem here is Twitter Bootstrap. I use this for show modals. Before show the modal with the video, i save cookies in browser.

When i put the video into a modal, the video can't play. When i click 2 times to the video, this video play. Only in Mozilla Firefox; Chrome, IE 7-8-9 works fine.

When i put the video out the modal. This play normally in all browser.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: I would not use FLV, I would just use MP4 and OGV. WMV is not supported. Regarding your issues with it playing, do you have a link?

Comment: @EthanLongTail Flash suppport MP4? Now i'm preparing a link with the video OGV, MP4 y FLV.

Comment: @EthanLongTail OGV is only support for one version of browser Mozilla. So i decide use webm instead of OGV. Can you tell me what encoder have to use for play in JW Player?

Comment: @EthanLongTail I edit my question. WEBM play correctly but before 1 or 2 clicks. I have a other link with this 3 videos in 3 formats and Play normaly.

Comment: Can you provide a link so I can troubleshoot this?

Comment: Ah yes, WebM is preferred over OGV.

Comment: And yes, Flash has supported MP4 for years...

Comment: Before that, you need to enter some information. Then, you choose a number.

Comment: Sorry, can you provide something that is on a page not in Facebook first? It becomes difficult to debug in that application.

Comment: Sorry, can't I just get a direct link to the page outside of FB so I don't have to go through all of that?

Comment: The reason this isn't working is because you are using Level / Modes, etc. These are V5 variables, and you are using the V6 Player. Modes should be removed entirely, and levels and can changed to sources instead. I would look over this migration doc. - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28834/migrating-from-jw5-to-jw6, it should help you with the migration between versions of the JW Player.

Comment: @EthanLongTail Can you give a doc for the API of V6 Player? What is the equivalence of modes and levels on V6?

Comment: API V6 is - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference, in V6, just remove moves, it is now controlled via "primary" and "fallback", and instead of using "levels" use "sources". Basically, just remove modes, and then change "levels" to "sources". I would also look over the migration doc that I provided to you in the post above..

Comment: So, "MODES" is handle automatically into the core of player and only i change "Levels" for "Sources"

Comment: Yes, change levels to sources and remove modes, that's it...

Comment: @EthanLongTail when you say "sources", You refer to sources tag into tag video? or is a option?

Comment: I am going to reply below with some sample code.

Comment: This discussion is growing too long and hard to follow. However it contains good information which should be integrated into the the question or an answer. Please do that and if needed, continue the discussion in the chat!

Comment: Yes, I moved it to an answer below! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since from looking at your link, I have been able to determine you are using JW6 now, not JW5, you should be using different code.

This code:

```
jwplayer('container').setup({
                height: 309,
                width: 549,
                levels: [
                    { file: "video.mp4" },
                    { file: "video.webm" },
                    { file: "video.flv" }
                ], 
                'modes': [
                    {type: 'html5'},
                    {type: 'flash', src: "jwplayer.flash.swf"},
                    {type: 'download'}
                ]
});
```

Should look like this, instead, for example:

```
jwplayer('container').setup({
                height: 309,
                width: 549,
                playlist: [{
                sources: [
                    { file: "video.mp4" },
                    { file: "video.webm" },
                    { file: "video.flv" }
                ]
                }]
});
```

This is because in JW6 modes is removed, HTML5 is already the primary mode, and "levels" is replaced by "sources".

Here is a migration doc - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28834/migrating-from-jw5-to-jw6

An example of multiple files being used in jw6 is here - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/29251/mp4-and-webm-formats

Comment: Ok, i remove "modes" and i change "levels" for "sources" into a "playlist". But, doesn't work. I update my application.

Comment: Don't work the video only in Mozilla Firefox. Because, when i play the video for first time, only the audio can be heard, but no the video. When i click for second time, i can view the video.

Comment: Maybe this occur for the order of sources?.. Or exist in V6 Player other way to alternate videos for browser? @EthanLongTail

Comment: You can download the videos from the URL that i share with you.

Comment: Your MP4 file has been encoded with a MOOV ATOM at the end of the file instead of the beginning of the file. I would recommend running this tool on your MP4 file - http://renaun.com/blog/2010/06/qtindexswapper-2/

Comment: I try all but only in mozilla firefox fail :(

Comment: OK.. I will running the tool on the MP4 file.

Comment: I would run that tool on the MP4 file. For WebM, I would recommend doing a re-encode using FireOGG. http://firefogg.org/

Comment: OK. I run the tool in MP4 file and FireOGG in WEBM file. However the error persist.. Maybe this occurrs for events block in my JwPlayer setup.

Comment: Can you put up another simple test page where the error is happening? Not in an app, just a basic test page, thanks.

Comment: I created a basic example and I noticed with surprise that works perfect in all browsers. With the MP4 and WEBM file without re-encode.
http://develop.tektonlabs.com/cms/example_link

Comment: In the console of Firefox i found this error when i try to play the video for first time: 
`Error playing media: %o   jwplayer.js (line 1)`
`CAPTIONS([object Object]) jwplayer.js (line 1)`
`CAPTIONS([object Object]) jwplayer.js (line 1)`
But this occurrs only in the APP into FB.
The example link don't have this error.

Comment: Maybe. This `Error playing media: %o` Why is it? In what cases get this error?

Comment: Where is that error being generated? I don't see it on that link though.

Comment: This error only occurrs in my app into FB iframe (Landing Page). But no into a external link with the videos.

Comment: When i try to play the video on Mozilla Firefox, in the console i have 3 partial content(206) of my webm file. So, in the first time i have a part of the video, then i have the error `%o`
In the second time, i have other partial content and i have, again, the error `%o`.
In the last time, i have another partial content, then i can view the video. Maybe this is the problem!

Comment: Maybe, if you are getting that error, maybe it has to do with a server side issue then? Since the error doesn't happen on the regular page and only happens in the app though, it becomes trickier.

Comment: OK, in my `httpd.conf` of my apache i added a mime-types webm: `addType video/webm` and I restarted my apache. However, the problem persist. Why MP4 no have this issue but WEBM have?

Comment: Does your server have gzip compression enabled?

Comment: I'll update my question with my configuration of .htaccess and mime.conf of my apache2. I disabled the gzip.

Comment: FINALLY!!.. I know what is the problem!!.. The problem is the Modal of twitter bootstrap.
When i put the video out the modal, this webm video works fine!